# Java how to write object to xlsx using SXSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a class that takes in a `List<Person>` and writes it out to an .xlsx file.

The person model's fields are:

```
String name
String address
Integer age
Double balance
```

The headers are `List<String> header = Arrays.asList("Name","Address","Age","Balance")`.

To create my headers I did:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
                            
SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("People's Info");
 
int rowNum = 0;
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
                  
int colNum = 0;
for (String header: headers) {
          Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(colNum++);
          cell.setCellValue(header);
}
 
// want to do a for loop and go through list of list of Person and write their info down
```

How would I go through the `List<Person>` and dynamically or smartly use their get method or something and correctly. And I am pretty sure I need to be able to set the cell value as a Double or String depending on the object fields type correct?

Comment: There are a lot of overriding constructors for Cell type

Comment: Do you mind posting a response to the question?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you've already done filling cells of one row by loop, for filling person data it will be the same:

```
int rowNum = 1;
for (Person person: personList) {
     Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
     Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
     cell0.setCellValue(person.getName());
     Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
     cell1.setCellValue(person.getAddress());
     Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
     cell2.setCellValue(person.getAge());
     Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
     cell3.setCellValue(person.getBallance());
}
```

Cell's type have different types of overriding constructors for double type, String, Integer, and so on.

How you asked, I'll add reflection getting fields of Person.class

```
    int rowNum = 1;
    for (Person person: personList) {
         Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
         Field[] fieldArray = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
         for(int i = 0; i < fieldArray.length; i++){
           Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
           cell.setCellValue(fieldArray[i].get(person));
         }
    }
```

But you should remember in this solution value of fields will be type Object, for simple cases you can cast this value to String type, but if you want to create a cell with different types you can't do it in the loop,  since for every individual cell you will create an individual cell, how I wrote above.

The main reason why you can't create cells dynamicly is a different types of fields in your DTO class

Comment: Ahhh i see i see. And is there a more dynamic way to do this instead of creating each cell and then using the getter for that person? Just wondering in case this is like a class with 20 fields

Comment: You can use a nested loop for setting cell values, but you should be aware of what should you do in each interaction of the nested loop, how can you get needed information in each interaction? You can solve this case by reflection for example, by getting fields array and then getting field by index and then increment the index of cell and index of array fields at the same time. The solution above is better and typically for apache poi api

Comment: Do you mind posting a snippet using the fields array? It looked really confusing to me when I googled it just now

Comment: I have added sniper with dynamic solution by reflection API

Comment: Hmm what did you mean by " but if you want to create a cell with different types you can't do it in the loop, since for every individual cell you will create an individual cell, how I wrote above." 

Does this mean it wont work because I have both String and Double in my fields?

Comment: `cell.setCellValue(fieldArray[i].get(person));`: This will not work. `Field.get` returns an `Object` and there is not a `Cell.setCellValue(Object value)`.